# How I compile dapp in browser just like I used to compile my Visual Studio code using xampp in my browser?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

Whenever I create/ edit some project on my Visual studio code, I put it  inside htdocs of xampp folder. Then I start Xampp control panel and give it some localhost port number so that I would compile that code using localhost:xxx url on my browser.
I was wondering, what is the equivalent process after I create some dapps using heroku, IPFS (heroku, IPFS is not my part of question here). What I mean is how I see it in browser its end result.
Sorry for being a noob as decentralized apps concept is relatively new.
I will be happy to share additional details that is needed to make this question complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a local server where your files are located.

1. Open your terminal
2. Go to your project folder
3. Install node.js if you don't have it already
4. Install the following utility globally: `npm i -g http-server`
5. Then in your terminal do: `http-server`

That way you'll be able to go to `localhost:8080` and see your dApp to interact with it. You could simply open your `index.html` file but metamask and other extensions won't work since they require you to run your app on the `http://` protocol instead of `file://`.

Comment: Thank you Meranus, I will do so